# MySQL + PHP - Results different on different computers? Cache?

Tags: php, mysql, caching, mysqli, centos

We have been running a local application for a bit over a year now and this problem has never come up.

We have a section of our application where a user will add a note to an account. Very simple table structure includes an account_id, user_id (who added the note) and a date.

The notes are still being added into the database just fine; however, when viewing the page, it is hit or miss on whether or not the note will actually display using PHP to query the database.

The only way I can get these notes to show up is by clearing the computer cache (again, doesn't always work) or clearing MySQL cache (which doesn't always work, either)

The application is being accessed from outside of our local network, as well, and this issue does not seem to happen from anybody using this method.

I think it is a cache issue, but I am honestly not familiar with this and have not run into this issue with anything before. Server is latest version of CentOS and we are running very simply MySQL queries via PHP.

Thanks, in advance, for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share the code and/or any other information that might help us to help you figure it out?

Comment: I figured the code wouldn't help much, as it doesn't seem to be the actual code that is causing it (has worked for over a year.) The code displaying the notes is a simple `SELECT * FROM notes WHERE account_id = '1';`

Running this command within phpMyAdmin returns, lets say, 2 results. On the page, only 1 result shows sometimes, unless the above cache clearing methods are used, then it will show 2 results. This problem doesn't seem to exist if accessed with our outward facing IP, but only internally with our local IP.

Comment: It looks like your local network is using a proxy; we got this problem at my office.

Comment: The local office is, in fact, not using a proxy, but why would this only come up now? The setup (server wise) has been the same since last year, and it has never happened in the past.